# Issue during casting map[string]interface {} to the []interface {}

Tags: go

I read following data from file:

```
[{"LastTs":1642081076,"LanErrors":77,"WanErrors":77},{"LastTs":1642081077,"LanErrors":78,"WanErrors":79}]
```

and I need to pass it as `[]interface {}` to some function. I'm trying to do the following:

```
var decoded []interface{}
err = json.Unmarshal(bytesFromFile, &decoded)
 
.......
    
someFunc(decoded) {
.....
}
```

As result I receive runtime exception: interface conversion: `interface {} is map[string]interface {}, not []interface {}`
Please explain how I could fix this issue.
P.S. Below is real code

```
func readMessagesFromSample(file string) []interface{} {
    sample, err := os.Open(file)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to open sample file")
    }
    defer sample.Close()

    reader := bufio.NewReader(sample)
    line, _, _ := reader.ReadLine()

    var decoded []interface{}
    err = json.Unmarshal(line, &decoded)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to unmarshal message: %v", err)
    }

    return decoded
}

func CalculateProblem(events []interface{}){
    prevErrorReceivedLan := events[0].([]interface{})[1].(uint64)
    prevErrorReceivedWan := events[0].([]interface{})[2].(uint64)
}
```

Comment: The code, as you included, is valid. It would've given the error you mentioned if you declared `var decoded interface{}` instead of `var decoded []interface{}`. Is this really what you are running?

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: `events[0]` is a `map[string]interface{}` as indicated by the panic.  Type assert to `map[string]interface{}` and use string key to get value.

Comment: @CeriseLimón - yes, and I need to fix it...

Comment: `uint64(events[0].(map[string]interface[])["LanErrors"].(float64))`

Comment: @BurakSerdar Unfortunately I cannot change CalculateProblem - I need to change output of readMessagesFromSample to use CalculateProblem

Comment: In that case, you have to use similar type assertions to convert the data into an array containing `[]interface{}` elements

Answer (score 0):

cast an event as map[string]interface{}.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

var s = `[{"LastTs":1642081076,"LanErrors":77,"WanErrors":77},{"LastTs":1642081077,"LanErrors":78,"WanErrors":79}]`

func main() {
    var events []interface{}

    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &events); err != nil {
        println(err)
    }

    for _, ev := range events {
        fmt.Printf("%v (%T)\n", ev, ev)

        m := ev.(map[string]interface{})

        fmt.Printf("lan: %v (%T)\n", m["LanErrors"], m["LanErrors"])
        fmt.Printf("wan: %v (%T)\n", m["WanErrors"], m["WanErrors"])
    }
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/rGVr4O-PmUP